# How can I add an extension to the "Open With..." dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code

My goal is to add a markdown rendering extension to the new "Open With..." dialog in VS Code so that it will open the file using the extension by default. This option is displayed when right-clicking a file in the Explorer panel. Since this is new in VS Code I haven't been able to find any documentation on how extensions can make use of the dialog. Although it is possible that I've just missed it.

These are my current options when used on a markdown file:

[image: Option 1: Text Editor. Option 2 Markdown Preview (Experimental)]

So my question is: where would I start if I wanted to add an extension to this list? I can't imagine it will be that much of a code change. And seeing as this can already be done with the built-in Markdown Preview I assume there must be some way I can accomplish this.